# Unable to convert the pandas to pyspark. It's showing there's dataframe has no percentile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Below is the Pandas code which is returning output

```
df_cols = df.columns.tolist()
spark_df_cols = spark_df['dic'].tolist()

i_names = []
i_quant = []

for i in df_cols:
    if i in spark_df_cols:
        i_names.append(i)
        i_quant.append(df[i].quantile(0.9))
        df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'dic': i_names, 'Percentile': i_quant})

df_1
```

The output is:

```
dic         Percentile
0   Annual...   72.6
1   par...      84.6
```

I'm trying to write the pyspark code which is below

```
df_cols = df.columns
spark_df_cols = spark_df.select('dic').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

i_names = []
i_quant = []

for i in df_cols:
    if i in spark_df_cols:
        i_names.append(i)
        print(i_names)
        i_quant.append(df.select(i).percentile(0.9))
        print(df.withColumn("Percentile", df[i].quantile(0.9)))
        df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'dic': i_names, 'Percentile': i_quant})

df_1
```

It's returning an error like

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'percentile'
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

its throwing that error as percentile is not a dataframe attribute or function it is a grouped dataframe sql function so you can do it using below code

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F 
df_cols = df.columns
spark_df_cols = spark_df.select('dic').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

i_names = []
i_quant = []

for i in df_cols:
    if i in spark_df_cols:
        i_names.append(i)
        print(i_names)
        i_quant.append(df.select(i).agg(F.expr(f"percentile({i},1)")).collect()[0][0])
        df.select(i).agg(F.expr(f"percentile({i},1)")).show()
        df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'dic': i_names, 'Percentile': i_quant})

df_1
```